# Set NavigationItem titleView Image Globally in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to setup a constant state for my Navigation Controller across my app. I am successful in getting colours declared in my App Delegate and working across the app, however am struggling to set the logo as the titleView. I am able to do this easily in individual view controllers just not globally.

Here is what I have in my App Delegate:

```
    let logo = UIImage(named: "Logo")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: logo)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 20)
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

    // It's this line which errors and doesn't work
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

**Update:**

Thanks to answer below I now understand that this isn't possible as described. I have put the creation and setup of the imageView in a global function and then call it will just one line in each of the views that I need it. I assume this is more efficient than rewriting all of the above on each view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppDelegate has no member variable called navigationItem, which is what causing the error. navigationItem is a member variable of UIViewController which is why you were able to used it in your ViewControllers. From Apple's documentation:

> This is a unique instance of UINavigationItem created to represent the
>   view controller when it is pushed onto a navigation controller. The
>   first time the property is accessed, the UINavigationItem object is
>   created. Therefore, you should not access this property if you are not
>   using a navigation controller to display the view controller. To
>   ensure the navigation item is configured, you can either override this
>   property and add code to create the bar button items when first
>   accessed or create the items in your view controller's
>   initialization code.

Comment: Thanks. What would you consider best practice to do this?

Comment: You can always put in your home ViewController as you would probably want the Icon to be displayed when they are in your home ViewController and not in all ViewControllers that you may have.